# PDF to Image - Magick++

Tags: c++, pdf, imagemagick, magick++

I want to convert a pdf to a series of images using magick++. I currently have this code:

```
Image  * img = new Image();
img->read(Tests+"finance-02-2007-multiples.pdf[0]");
```

Tests is a variable which contains the folder path. The "[0]" means that I want the first page to read in an image.

However, this code snippet does not work. The exception "Magick::ErrorDelegate" appears.
I know that ImageMagick uses GhostScript to render the page. Can it be that i need to do something to enalbe GhostScript in ImageMagick first?

Or has someone an ide how to get the code to work?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is telling you that cannot find GhostScript on your computer.

In order to read a PDF using Magick, you must have GhostScript installed. Magick++ has a (limited)  internal support only for writing a pdf.  It actually embeds an image in pdf. The reason is that GhostScript is licenced as GPL and cannot be included in Magick, but fortunately can be used if installed by user :).

Magick checks for a GhostScript via registry. Make sure you have installed a verion of GhostScript and that installation has created one of the keys below in **HKEY_CURRENT_USER** or **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE**.

> "SOFTWARE\GPL Ghostscript",
>
> "SOFTWARE\GNU Ghostscript",
>
> "SOFTWARE\AFPL Ghostscript",
>
> "SOFTWARE\Aladdin Ghostscript"

Hope it helps