# Magick::readImage return exception System cannot find the file specified (pdf file)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, imagemagick

Using ImageMagick in Visual Studio 2010, the readImage method can't load one pdf file, returning std::exception. This is the code:

```
try
{
   Magick::readImages( &imageList, "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\doc.pdf" );
}
catch(std::exception &ex)
{
    std::cout << ex.what()<< std::endl;
}
catch(...){
    std::cout << "No chatched" << std::endl;
}
```

The file exist and path is well formed. The output is:

```
PDFDelegateFailed `The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Its pass when I execute from cmd.

Comment: Place `doc.pdf` in the same directory as the executable and try to open `Magick::readImages( &imageList, "doc.pdf" );`, if this works than its your path

Comment: @JamesMore I was try it but investigating, the problem is related about ghostscript that I have not installed on my machine. I'm right?

Comment: Try to open a different file format and see it it stills fails. What is your definition of `&imageList`?

Comment: It looks like you need to install ghostscript as Magick uses ghostscript to read .pdf files as you said, [PDF to Image Magic++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885194/pdf-to-image-magick?rq=1)

Comment: `&imageList is a std::vector<Image> imageList;` and of course, vector is included. As you say, the problem is about I'm not using ghostscript.