# Magick++ error with converting byte to Blob

Tags: c++, pdf, image-processing, magick++

Good day,

I have a problem converting my pdf to images in magick++. I am quite confused if the problem is in the DLL of Magick++ because when I try it to another project all good but when I used the DLL, the error persists:

> w3wp.exe: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/blob.c/BlobToImage/412

My code is

```
__declspec(dllexport) char* __stdcall Scan(BYTE * pdf, int nSize){
    Magick::Blob blob((const void *)pdf, nSize);
    try{
        Magick::ReadOptions options;
        options.density(Magick::Geometry(300, 300));

        std::list<Magick::Image> images;
        Magick::readImages(&images, blob, options);  //The error persists in here

        size_t i;
        std::list<Magick::Image>::iterator image;

        for (image = images.begin(), i = 0; image != images.end(); image++, i++){

        }
    }
}
```

I really appreciate any help, I am stuck on this one.

Comment: Looks like pdf could not be read as image. I'm not familiar with Magic but my guess would be - You need some pdf reading plugin - or you need to find different API wich will extract images from pdf before processing them by readImage API

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDF to Image - Magick++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885194/pdf-to-image-magick)

Comment: Good day @ArtemyVysotsky, Though at some PDF files I tried it works but there some of them do not and return the said error, I already tried using the imageinfo in readimages but no luck.

Comment: Not all pdf files contain images. If pdf contains text it probably requires different approach (rendering image from pdf) when pdf containing image - just extracting image from pdf. Do you know which of the two make you a problem?

Comment: What are the first 8 bytes of `pdf` data? The error states that ImageMagick doesn't understand what file format this is, and can't pass the read request to the ghostscript delegate.

Comment: Also remember to invoke `Magick::InitializeMagick` before using the library to ensure the environment is initialized correctly.